# Dataflow "Error processing pipeline" running Apache Beam pipeline in Go with fixed window

Tags: go, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm trying to test windows with Apache Beam and Go SDK, and for that I modified/merged the [streaming_wordcap](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/go/examples/streaming_wordcap/wordcap.go) and [windowed_wordcount](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/go/examples/windowed_wordcount/windowed_wordcount.go), and I'm running it on Dataflow.
According to [BEAM-5378](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-5378) these two examples are ok and running, but I'm unable to run my modified version or the original version of `windowed_wordcount`, which seams to be a problem with windows or the way I'm running the examples.

The log messages say basically nothing. From Dataflow logs I only get `"Error processing pipeline"` and on the CLI from Apache Beam I get

```
...
2021/07/13 23:24:47 Job state: JOB_STATE_PENDING ...
2021/07/13 23:25:17 Failed to execute job: job 2021-07-13_15_24_45-391245677226170369 failed
exit status 1
```

How I'm running the examples:

```
> go run main.go --runner=dataflow --region=europe-west1 --project=<project> --staging_location=gs://<bucket>/<path>
```

Any thoughts on what can be the problem?

[Edit 1]
Go SDK version from the go.mod

```
github.com/apache/beam v2.31.0+incompatible
```

Comment: Go SDK is still relatively new so I suggest asking in Beam's user list: https://beam.apache.org/community/contact-us/

Comment: I created a ticket for it https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-12636